# Can I use a temporary access token instead of username and password to create a login session?

Tags: authentication, security-token

I think I have to write a custom plugin for this, but just for exhaustion, is this already possible? Or anyone knows a plugin that can do it?

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla

Comment: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=955371

Comment: Actually, both Bard and ChatGPT can write drafts for such a plugin. Heh.

Comment: I would look at the RememberMe plugin of the core as, from memory, I recall looking at it in detail a few years ago and learnt about how the sessions and 'login' works without the username/password.

Comment: @Irata Thanks! I'll check. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any plugin that does it, but one can implement it as follows:

## 1. Have a plugin

Make sure you have a plugin, which looks like

```
class YourPlugin extends JPlugin {
    //...
}
```

## 2. Have a flag that will determine whether log in is needed:

```
    /**
    * Boolean user in order to determine whether we need to log in with this plugin
    *
    * @var boolean
    */
    protected $toLoginUser = false;
```

The reason for this is that before we save the user, we acknowledge based on the old user data that it indeed needs to end with a log in, so after save we can actually trigger the login.

## 3. onUserBeforeSave

Determine whether we need to log in and if so, set the flag to true:

```
    public function onUserBeforeSave($oldUser, $isnew, $newUser)
    {
        //...
        /**
         * We load the user and save it into a variable so the criteria that decides whether we need to log in will be easier to grasp
         */
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        /**
         * We determine whether we need to log in with a user:
         * - nobody is logged in right now
         * - the user was blocked and is being unblocked
         * - the user has an activation token which will be removed
         * - the activation token of the user matches the value of the "token" GET parameter
         */
        if (
            (!$user->id) &&
            ($oldUser["block"] == 1) && ($newUser["block"] == 0) &&
            (!empty($oldUser["activation"])) && empty($newUser["activation"]) &&
            ($oldUser["activation"] === Factory::getApplication()->input->get("token", null))
        ) {
            $this->toLoginUser = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

## 4. onUserAfterSave

After saving the user, do the actual log in

```
    public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
    {
        //...
        //If we need to log in, then we log in :)
        if ($this->toLoginUser) {
            //We define the options to be passed
            $options = [
                "remember" => false,
                "return" => "your/url/here",
                "entry_url" => JURI::base() . "/index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login",
                "action" => "core.login.site"
            ];
            //and create an AuthenticationResponse object with the correct credentials
            $ar = new AuthenticationResponse();
            $ar->status = 1;
            $ar->type = "Joomla";
            $ar->error_message = "";
            $ar->username = $user["username"];
            $ar->email = $user["email"];
            $ar->fullname = $user["name"];
            //This is the actual login, with the correct AuthenticationResponse and options
            JFactory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onUserLogin', [(array) $ar, $options]);
        }
        //...
        return true;
    }
```

Note that you will also need to

```
use Joomla\CMS\Authentication\AuthenticationResponse;
```